# How to change text on done button ios keyboard

Tags: ios, button, web-applications

I'm working on Web base App right now. (not native Obj/swift app)
so in my xcode only have view to show my web app.

I want to change "done" button text (the one on the top of keyboard) to something else.
I want to change all of them not just one specific textbox
Is it possible to do that ?

Comment: so you are not implementing a native ios app (ObjC/Swift), but a web application and you just want to change the keyboard for one of the textfield in your web page?

Comment: yes for the first question, and no I want to change all off it not just for one text field. can you help me ?  thanks

Comment: Can some one help me?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a Textfield, it won't support the enter functionality.

Use a UITextView to achive the enter functionality

Comment: Then pls add comment, don't react by answer.

Comment: he should have at least 50 reps to comment

Comment: And he just downVoted it :(

Comment: I'm not using them at all, its a web application but I mention ios in case its possible to set default keyboard setting or something

Comment: hey for a textfield multiple lines are not supported.so the enter function won't work ..You have the use a textview equivalent

Comment: I'm developing on web base app not native swift app sorry
by the way I dint downvoted you. but thanks for answer anyway

Comment: under stood .But the component you are using in web app supports multiple lines?

Comment: I might not clear on that sorry by Enter I mean like go or return

Comment: I will explain. You can't just remove the done button..
the keyboard is displaying this button based on the view in which you are entering the data.So if you are filling data in a view that support multiple lines it will show enter

Comment: so then right now my problem is on my keyboard bottom left is "go" because its in the form tag. how can I change to "done" button and not having "done" button on the top of the keyboard. thanks